# ¿Como guardar mis datos que los tengo almacenado en SQLITE a MYSQL remoto (Volley)?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Estoy tratando de descifrar y la verdad que estoy ya muy quemado y no logro darme cuenta de como almacenar mi lista SQLITE (carro de articulos y precios) en una base de datos MYSQL remota (estoy trabajando con volley);

El tema es asi
primero recupero mis datos de SQLITe y lo almaceno en una lista:

```
    private List<PedidosBean> recuperaListaSQLite() {
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(getApplicationContext(), "pedidos", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT nombre_art, precio_art, codigo_art, cantidad_art FROM pedidos", null);

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            PedidosBean articulos = new PedidosBean();
            articulos.setNombre_art(cursor.getString(0));
            articulos.setPrecio_art(cursor.getDouble(1));
            articulos.setCodigo_art(cursor.getInt(2));
            articulos.setCantidad_art(cursor.getInt(3));

            listaSQLite.add(articulos);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }


    bd.close();

    return listaSQLite;

}
```

Luego no se que hacer para llevarlo a mysql... 
lo convierto en JsonArray? Juro que no me doy cuenta. por favor una ayudita?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de romperme el coco (esto es lo lindo de la programacion) encontre la solucion con la libreria GSON.. asi que recupere los datos de sqlite lo almacene en un objeto de tipo List y con el fabuloso GSON lo converti en json para enviarlo al web service.